# C++デバッグについて

Tags: c++, macos

[こちら](http://homepage1.nifty.com/Ike/ComShogi/01.html)のサイトを参考にコンピュータ将棋を作成中です。
今回質問したいのは、C++のデバッグ方法です。理想はRailsでいう`binding.pry`とかで処理を止めて変数の中身を見たいのです。

そこでコマンドラインからデバッグしたい衝動にかられていたこともあり、macに標準で備わっているという`lldb`を使ってこの[サイト](http://homepage1.nifty.com/Ike/ComShogi/02.html)のchapter2をデバッグしてみました。以下打ち込んだコマンドです。

makefileでコンパイルしたあと、

```
lldb ./shogi
b kyokumen.c:29
r
```

ブレイクポイントを設定し`kyokumen.c`の29行目で止めたかったのですが、、普通に`./shogi`コマンドを打ったときのように将棋プログラムが起動してしまい止まったかどうかがわかりません。

理想は以下のような形で止めたいです。

```
(lldb) r
Process 93890 launched: '/Path/To/hoge' (x86_64)
Process 93890 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x53c0ae, 0x0000000100000f23 hoge`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007fff5fbff460) + 51 at hoge.c:6, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x0000000100000f23 hoge`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007fff5fbff460) + 51 at hoge.c:6
   3    int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   4        char *test = "This is a debug demo.";
   5        char *name = "edo";
-> 6        int age = 20;
   7
   8        printf("Name: %s, Age: %d\n", name, age);
   9
(lldb)
```

何か解決方法ございましたらご教示いただきたいです。

Comment: こちらの環境が Mac OSX ではないので動作確認が取れないのですが、`(lldb) process launch --tty` とすれば別個にターミナルが開いてそちらで `shogi` コマンドが実行されるかと思います。

Comment: 簡単なプログラムでデバッグ可能か確認できますか？参考になるページ：http://qiita.com/edo_m18/items/9b6be35907433e1c743e  次に@yasuharu519 さんの回答にもあるように デバッグ情報付きでコンパイルされているかの切り分けが必用だと感じてます。よく分からなければ makefile の内容を質問に追記してもらえれれば回答が付くかもしれません。

Comment: 回答ではないですが、OSX環境であれば、Xcodeを使ってはどうでしょうか。lldbを使うよりだいぶ楽ですよ。
テンプレートは、OSX Application - CommandLineToolを使うことになると思います。makefileが単純であれば、xcodeprojectにするのはそれほど難しくはありません。

Answer (score 2):

コンパイラは何を使っていますか? コンパイルの際に、`-g` などのオプションを付けてデバッグ情報付きでコンパイルを行わないと、ブレークポイントで止めるといったことができないように思います。

Comment: makefileの中身のファイルそれぞれに足しして`-g`オプションをつけるとうまくいきました。お手数おかけしました。
みなさまありがとうございます！xcodeでのデバッグも検討してみます。